# ng2-smart-table subscribe edit

Tags: typescript, ng2-smart-table

I want to manage the edit function of my ng2-smart-table but this code does not work for me, I have something wrong?

HTML

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (edit)="onEdit($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Component

```
onEdit(event:any):void{
console.log("edit model");}
```

I can add new buttons and manage your behavior, any way I would like to know if I can subscribe to that event and how to do it

Comment: the functions deleteConfirm, editConfirm and createConfirm work fine but create, edit, and delete do not, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because ng2-smart-table needs the mode value to be modified in its settings

```
settings = {
actions: {
  columnTitle: 'Actions'
},
mode: 'external',
```